# How to import the CSV in R reading word by word?

Tags: r, csv

I want to import a CSV data in R. It is a one line data and have comma separated entries. The dummy of the data is provided as follows:

```
Id,SecoId,TertioID,CreateDate,Lat,Long,Duration,Istrue,JournalDate,Post 3232,123,345,30/04/14 2:00,11.726,11.728,5,FALSE,02/04/2014 05:02 +01:00,ABC 3233,124,346,30/04/14 3:00,11.789,11.779,6,TRUE,03/04/2014 06:00 +01:00,BCD
```

this is a single lined CSV. how to read it correctly.
This is a dummy dataset only. The dataset provided to me have 35 variables and 10000 observations. Can anyone provide me with the correct logic and a relevant code.

EDIT: Desired Output is:

```
 Id   SecoId TertioID   CreateDate   Lat     Long   Duration Istrue        JournalDate         Post
3232   123     345    30/04/14 2:00 11.726  11.728    5       FALSE  02/04/2014 05:02 +01:00   ABC
3233   124     346    30/04/14 3:00 11.789  11.779    6       TRUE   03/04/2014 06:00 +01:00   BCD

Logic Thought by me:

1. Count the number of variables in the dataset.
2. read the file word by word.
3. Store the values between "," in a cell of the table, and doesnot alter the spaces between the values i.e. in CreateDate value it accepts "30/04/14 2:00" as a single value.
4. the loop runs until the last variable is encountered. and when the loop ends the new row is created and observation is stored from there.
```

Though i was not successful in creation of a relevant code.

If reading word by word is possible in R then can anyone help me out for the relevant solution?

Comment: You should be able to achieve what you want by reading line by line, which is the default behavior for `read.csv()`.

Comment: Please read the edits @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 2):

If `inp` is the single line of input then compute the number of fields, `k`, and from that compute a pattern `pat` to match them.  Use `gsub` to insert a newline after each pattern match and finally read in the result using `read.csv`:

```
k <- length(read.table(text = inp, comment = " ", sep = ",")) # no of fields
pat <- sprintf("((.*?,){%d}.*? +)", k-1) # pattern to match k fields
read.csv(text = gsub( pat, "\\1\n", inp), strip.white = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```

If `inp` is the input line at the end of the question the code above outputs this data frame:

```
  PulseId JourneyId TransmissionId    CreateDate      Lat      Long Speed
1  367515      3237              1 30/04/14 4:02 51.53749 -3.590589     7
2 3657521      3237              1 30/04/14 4:02 51.53704 -3.589859    11
3 3657522      3237              1 30/04/14 4:02 51.53695 -3.589748    12
  Heading HAccuracy Altitude VAccuracy DDuration DDistance DHeading  RSL
1     129        15       98         0         1  8.639347     1292 22.4
2     141        10       99         0         1 11.811534        1 22.4
3     144        10      100         0         1 12.805132        3 22.4
  RSLRoadTypeId RSLValidation RSLCountryId PulseTypeId IsNightTime Congestion
1             2             1          826           2       FALSE          0
2             5             1          826           2       FALSE          0
3             2             1          826           2       FALSE          0
  Idle AccelBrake  Cornering IsNearRailway IsSpeedValid Familiar IntLat3
1    0  0.2038734 1.60655912         FALSE         TRUE        1   51537
2    0  0.0000000 0.01957049         FALSE         TRUE        1   51537
3    0  0.1019367 0.06404887         FALSE         TRUE        1   51537
  IntLong3              LocalDateTime Smoothness PhoneId       PolicyId
1    -3591 30/04/2014 05:02:45 +01:00          2      43 4663627m000010
2    -3590 30/04/2014 05:02:51 +01:00          0      43 4663627m000010
3    -3590 30/04/2014 05:02:52 +01:00          1      43 4663627m000010
                          DevideId        DNA
1 829eba198fa483a49f14b66b8f1dadb5 0.04444444
2 829eba198fa483a49f14b66b8f1dadb5 0.04444444
3 829eba198fa483a49f14b66b8f1dadb5 0.04444444
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# Read in data
vec <- "Id,SecoId,TertioID,CreateDate,Lat,Long,Duration,Istrue,JournalDate,Post 3232,123,345,30/04/14 2:00,11.726,11.728,5,FALSE,02/04/2014 05:02 +01:00,ABC 3233,124,346,30/04/14 3:00,11.789,11.779,6,TRUE,03/04/2014 06:00 +01:00,BCD"

# Put in delimiters for where the line breaks should have been and split the data for each line.
vec <- unlist(strsplit(gsub("([a-z]|[A-Z]) (\\d)", "\\1;\\2", vec), ";"))

# Process data for each column
list.split <- strsplit(vec, ",")

# Write out the data to a matrix
mat.out <- matrix(unlist(list.split), ncol = length(list.split[[1]]), nrow = length(list.split), byrow = TRUE)
colnames(mat.out) <- mat.out[1,]
mat.out <- mat.out[-1,]
```

Comment: thanks @JackeJR but i have a CSV file with 10000 observations.

Comment: you can just do a `readLine` to readthe whole file into a vector.

Comment: @JackeJR This is my feeling and I don't think the OP really needs to read one word and a time.

Comment: well i thought that reading the file Word by word could help me keep the values between the delimiters. as the values also contains spaces so i was unable to read the data correctly. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @JackeJR will let you know if this works. I really want to know your logic behind this code.

Comment: He is reading the file one line at a time, then splitting the line using regex.  This allows him to simulate reading one word at a time.

Comment: Warning message:
In matrix(unlist(list.split), ncol = length(list.split[[1]]), nrow = length(list.split),  :
  data length [138] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of columns [35]

Comment: is that on your data or the example data? I ran the exact code above and had no errors.

Comment: no it is on the actual data that i was provided with. @JackeJR

Comment: Without seeing the data, I won't be able to help